# Why does the compiler insist my function is inline when it's not?

Tags: delphi, compiler-errors, delphi-xe2

Why am I getting

> [DCC Error] ProjectCOWArray.dpr(23): E2426 Inline function must not have asm block

```
program ProjectCOWArray;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

type
  PRefCount = ^TRefCount;
  TRefCount = array[0..1] of integer;


  TCOWArray<T> = record
  private
    fData: TArray<T>;
  private
    procedure IncRefCount;  <<-- not inline  
  end;


{ TCOWArray<T> }

procedure TCOWArray<T>.IncRefCount;
asm
  {$if defined(win32)}
  mov eax,fData;
  lock inc dword ptr [eax - 8];
  {$ifend}
  {$if defined(win64)}
  mov rax,fData;
  lock inc dword ptr[rax -12];
  {$ifend}
end;

begin
end.
```

Delphi XE2 does not have `AtomicIncrement`, so how do I solve this issue?
It'd like to retain the assembler, because otherwise I cannot have the `lock` prefix in and I do not want to use `InterlockedIncrement` because that's a WinAPI function and I do not want that kind of overhead.

Comment: Perhaps you should choose what is your question about - compiler "inline asm bug" or a search for a interlocked increment alternative.

Comment: It's clear the question is about the compiler message, @Krom. The part about the increment code is to preempt off-topic comments asking why he's bothering with assembler in the first place instead of using the API.

Comment: FWIW I don't understand why you want to meddle with the ref count directly. There's no need to do that.

Comment: If you take a look at the System.pas you can see how you can modify the refcount of an array without the use of assembly.

Comment: @StefanGlienke, this is the code in System.pas: `procedure _DynArrayAddRef;
asm
{     ->EAX     Pointer to heap object }
        TEST    EAX,EAX
        JE      @@exit
   LOCK INC     dword ptr [EAX-8]
@@exit:
end;` So I'm confused....

Comment: @Johan you should look at the implementation surrounded by {$IFDEF PUREPASCAL}.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because the generics functionality is implemented on top of the inlining engine. The same restrictions that apply to inline functions apply to generic functions. The compiler writers just haven't taken the extra step to make the error messages specific to generics rather than inline functions.

I think that calling `InterlockedIncrement` is probably your best option, for Delphi versions that don't have the `AtomicIncrement` intrinsic. Or, alternatively, create your own version of  `AtomicIncrement`, that is only defined in versions of Delphi that do not include it. And that function can be written in asm. Well, it clearly has to be written in asm of course.

```
{$IFNDEF AtomicFunctionsAvailable}
function AtomicIncrement(var Target: Integer): Integer;
asm
  ....
end;
{$ENDIF}
```

Or as @TLama suggests, you can use `TInterlocked` from the `System.SyncObjs` unit to provide atomic operations.

With all that said, I see no need to meddle with the internals in this way. Implement a copy of write array by calling `SetLength(...)` whenever you write to the array. For instance, here's a very simple copy on write array implementation:

```
unit COWArray;

interface

type
  TCOWArray<T> = record
  private
    FItems: TArray<T>;
    function GetLength: Integer;
    procedure SetLength(Value: Integer);
    function GetItem(Index: Integer): T;
    procedure SetItem(Index: Integer; const Value: T);
  public
    class function New(const Values: array of T): TCOWArray<T>; static;
    property Length: Integer read GetLength write SetLength;
    property Items[Index: Integer]: T read GetItem write SetItem; default;
  end;

implementation

function TCOWArray<T>.GetLength: Integer;
begin
  Result := System.Length(FItems);
end;

procedure TCOWArray<T>.SetLength(Value: Integer);
begin
  System.SetLength(FItems, Value); // SetLength enforces uniqueness
end;

function TCOWArray<T>.GetItem(Index: Integer): T;
begin
  Result := FItems[Index];
end;

procedure TCOWArray<T>.SetItem(Index: Integer; const Value: T);
begin
  System.SetLength(FItems, System.Length(FItems)); // SetLength enforces uniqueness
  FItems[Index] := Value;
end;

class function TCOWArray<T>.New(const Values: array of T): TCOWArray<T>;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  System.SetLength(Result.FItems, System.Length(Values));
  for i := 0 to high(Values) do
    Result.FItems[i] := Values[i];
end;

end.
```

Comment: Yes, `SetLength()` does the job.

Comment: @LURD I know you've done COW work before. Is this broadly how you approach it?

Comment: Yes, every attemt to write to the internal `FItems` array must call `SetLength`. No need to dig deeper than that for faster performance.

Comment: The unit tests confirm the double increments. I did not know that a SetLength does not check if `newlength <> oldlength`. BTW you can shorten `New()` like so: `begin
  Result.fItems:= Copy(Value);
end;`

Comment: @Johan `Copy()` won't fly with an open array

Comment: Note that if `T` is a record, it is better to have the item property as a pointer to T.

Comment: @LURD, from a storage perspective I agree, but how to retain the COW properties when using pointers instead of direct storage. Records do not have reference counting.

Comment: @LURD If you do that, you cannot copy on write because you cannot detect the write. Because it is done through the pointer.

Comment: I got that all mixed up with another project, sorry. Must be the heat or too much late football watching.

Answer (score 4):

Even if you could call `InterlockedIncrement`, you'd still have the obstacle of attaining a reference to the array's reference-count field. You don't really need it, though. Instead, you can let the compiler do the work for you. Declare another array variable and assign to it to increment the count. Then type-cast it to a non-managed type and set it back to a null pointer. The reference count will remain intact even after the variable goes out of scope.

```
var
  dummy: TArray<T>;
begin
  dummy := fData; // increment reference count
  Pointer(dummy) := nil; // circumvent decrement
end;
```

This technique works for incrementing the reference count of anything, including arrays, strings, and interfaces.

To decrement is just one line:

```
begin
  Pointer(dummy) := fData;
  // reference count decrements automatically at scope's end
end;
```

Comment: Wow Rob, that is beautiful. A much better hack.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks David for explaining the all important **why**

A possible solution is to lift the AtomicIncrement out of the generic record and into a hack.

```
program ProjectCOWArray;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

type
  PRefCount = ^TRefCount;
  TRefCount = array[0..1] of integer;

  TCOWArray<T> = record
  private
    fData: TArray<T>;
  private
    procedure IncRefCount;
  end;

{ TCOWArray<T> }

type TAnyOldDynArray = array of integer;

procedure AtomicIncrementDynArrayRefCount(const AnArray: TAnyOldDynArray);
asm
  {$if defined(win32)}
  mov eax,AnArray;
  lock inc dword ptr [eax - 8];
  {$else}
  mov rax,AnArray;
  lock inc dword ptr [rax -12];
  {$ifend}
end;

procedure TCOWArray<T>.IncRefCount;
begin
  AtomicIncrementDynArrayRefCount(TAnyOldDynArray(fData));
end;

begin
end.
```