# How to increase the reference count of subarrays when the refcount of the holding array increases?

Tags: arrays, delphi, delphi-xe2, reference-counting, copy-on-write

I have a COWarray that works OK, but now I want to expand the number of dimensions like so:

```
type
  TCOWArray2<T> = record
  private
    type
      TItem = record
        fItems: TArray<T>;
        fStart, fFinish: NativeInt;
      end;
  private
    fItems: array of TItem;
  private
     methods
  public
     ....
  end;
```

The array splits up its items in blocks. Every sub array has e.g. 100 items and the mean array has however many items are needed.
To the outside only a one dimensional array is presented, but internally the data of type `T` is stored in the subarray.

This way I can have copy of write with very little copying going on when a single item changes. 
Instead of cloning all 20,000 items, only 100 items are clones plus the mean array with 200 items, i.e. only 300 items a nearly 99% reduction of effort and storage.

The problem is that I need to keep track of changes in the reference count of the main array and propagate those to the sub-arrays.

Something like:

```
procedure TCOWArray<T>.SomeMember.AddRef;
var
  Item: TItem;
begin
  inherited;
  for Item in fItems do Item.IncreaseRefCount;
end;
```

*Obviously for performance reasons I will use a plain for i loop*

**How do I do this?**
I was thinking of adding a custom TInterfaced Object, but I'm not sure how to make it work.

Comment: This is deja vu. You solve the problem using `SetLength` rather than manually screwing with the ref count.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, No david, I need to **increase** the reference count of the child arrays, not reset it to 1. Resetting it to 1 is done using `SetLength` I know that now (thanks) and that works. I now need the reverse operation.

Comment: Once you figure out which subarray to write to, use SetLength() on that one.

Comment: Call SetLength on the main array. That gives you a unique copy, which is what you want for the main array. It will automatically increment the reference counts of all the subarrays. Now call SetLength on the subarray you plan to modify. That makes it unique, too. In other words, you already solved this problem for `TCOWArray<T>`, and now you're trying to re-solve it for `TCOWArray<TCOWArray<T>>` without realizing that it's just a specialization of what you've already done.

Comment: Aha, ok that makes sense. I did it the other way round and I was stuck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to be the second in a multi-dimensional series of questions.

The first question in the series, the outer dimension, was here: [Why does the compiler insist my function is inline when it's not?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24286088) Although the question title concerned an error message, it ultimately became a question concerning the implementation of a copy-on-write array. That was the one-dimensional version of the question.

Now we move on to this question. This is the two-dimensional version. We solve it the same way as the first question. Because it is actually the exact same issue. Once we can solve it for a one-dimensional array, the same solution works for an N dimensional array.

When you need to modify an element of the array, call `SetLength` on your internal array. This gives you a unique outer array. Any copying that happens here, only copies references to the inner sub-arrays.

Then identify the inner sub-array that you need to operate on. When you've done that, call `SetLength` again to make that inner sub-array unique. Then modify the value.

It does not matter how many dimensions you add. The answer is always the same. I'm hoping that this question can terminate the series!  ;-)

Comment: Yes, that makes sense, I was working from the inside-out, but you need to work it from the outside in. Very easy once you realize how it works.